# Fabricjs - Objects created in "added" event are not fully restored by loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm running into a problem when I try to serialize my canvas as json and later on restore it with loadFromJSON.

The following jsfiddle is just an extract of a larger project, but shows the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/3y97d7nj/1/

```
fabric.MyRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: "myRect",
    initialize(options={}){
    this.callSuper("initialize", options)

    this.on("moving", function(){
        if(this.tri){
        this.tri.top = this.getTop()
        this.tri.left = this.getLeft()
        this.tri.setCoords()
      }
    })
    this.on("added", function(){        
        this.tri = new fabric.Triangle({
        left: this.getLeft(),
        top: this.getTop(),
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fill: "red"
      })
        this.canvas.add(this.tri)
    })
  }
})
fabric.MyRect.fromObject = function(obj){
    return new fabric.MyRect(obj)
}

let c = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas")

c.add(new fabric.MyRect({
    top:0,
  left:0,
  width:100,
  height:100,
  fill:"green"
 }))

c.add(new fabric.MyRect({
    top:100,
  left:100,
  width:100,
  height:100,
  fill:"blue"
 }))

c.renderAll()

let canvasModel = c.toObject()
canvasModel.objects = canvasModel.objects.filter(e => e.type !== "triangle")
c.clear()
c.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvasModel), c.renderAll.bind(c))
```

The MyRect subclass adds a new Triangle when it is "added" to the canvas from within the "object:added" callback. If I do NOT add a second instance of MyRect to the canvas (line: 39) everything works fine, but I run into problems with the fiddle as is, with two MyRect instances.

If you run the fiddle, both MyRect instances are rendered on the canvas, but only one has the Triangle attached to it from the "object:added" callback.

I'm not sure if the "object:added" callback is even intended to add further objects to the canvas. But as writtern above, this is only an extract of a bigger application which would really hard to be refactored into something like a Group etc.

I'm using version: 1.6.2

Problem happens in recent Chrome as well as Firefox.

Any help is really appreciated.

Best Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the triangles are not getting added again in the canvas I don't know why, look the fiddle I added manually the first triangle because is not added to the canvas:

```
      fabric.MyRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: "myRect",
    initialize(options={}){
      this.callSuper("initialize", options)

      this.on("moving", function(){
      console.log('tri', this.tri)
        if(this.tri){
          this.tri.top = this.getTop()
          this.tri.left = this.getLeft()
          this.tri.setCoords()
        }
      })
      this.on("added", function(){              
        this.tri = new fabric.Triangle({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          fill: "red"
        })
        this.tri.id = parseInt(Math.random() * 100000)
        console.log('add', this.tri, this.tri.id)
        this.canvas.add(this.tri)
      })
    }
  })
  fabric.MyRect.fromObject = function(obj){
    return new fabric.MyRect(obj)
  }

  window.c = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas")

  c.add(new fabric.MyRect({
    top:0,
    left:0,
    width:100,
    height:100,
    fill:"green"
   }))

  c.add(new fabric.MyRect({
    top:100,
    left:100,
    width:100,
    height:100,
    fill:"blue"
   }))

  c.renderAll()

  let canvasModel = c.toObject()
  canvasModel.objects = canvasModel.objects.filter(e => e.type !== "triangle")

  c.clear()
  console.log('canvasmodel', canvasModel)
  c.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvasModel), c.renderAll.bind(c))

  c.add(c._objects[0].tri)

  c.renderAll()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/3y97d7nj/2/